# Reshaping the path with keypoints in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

My problem consists of being unable to achieve simple drag and release deformation of the svg path in D3.js. My goal is to make it work similarly like moving the nodes in vector editors, albeit only in y direction. Now I manage to move keypoints (orange data points) but the path stays out of sync with the movement of the points.This is my approach:

```
     var sample_data = [{
      'id': 0,
      'x': 2001,
      'y': 10
    }, {
      'id': 1,
      'x': 2002,
      'y': 12
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'x': 2003,
      'y': 9
    }, {
      'id': 3,
      'x': 2004,
      'y': 10
    }, {
      'id': 4,
      'x': 2005,
      'y': 11
    }, {
      'id': 5,
      'x': 2006,
      'y': 8
    },{
      'id': 6,
      'x': 2007,
      'y': 10
    },{
      'id': 7,
      'x': 2008,
      'y': 11
    },{
      'id': 8,
      'x': 2009,
      'y': 9
    },{
      'id': 9,
      'x': 2010,
      'y': 10
    }
  ];

var indices = d3.range(0, sample_podaci.length);
console.log(indices);

//Main dragging function - possibly this is the problematic one...

function dragmove(d) {
    var y = d3.event.y;
    var no_tac = d3.select(this).attr("ta_id");
    var kriva_path = d3.select('path#serija');
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + y + ")");
    sample_podaci[no_tac].y = -d3.event.y;
    kriva_path.attr("d", lineFunc(sample_podaci));
   }

  function drag_col_start(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "#b91d47");
  }

  function drag_col_end(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "#e3a21a");
  }


  var drag_function = d3.behavior.drag() //function for dragging behaviour
  .origin(function() {
     var t = d3.select(this);
     return {x: t.attr("x") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[0],
             y: t.attr("y") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[1]};
             })
    .on('dragstart', drag_col_start)
    .on('drag', dragmove)
    .on('dragend', drag_col_end);

  var vis = d3.select("#d3_primer"),
    WIDTH = 900,
    HEIGHT = 450,
    MARGINS = margin,
    xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(sample_data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
      }),
      d3.max(sample_data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
    ]),

    yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(sample_data, function (d) {
        return d.y-5;
      }),
      d3.max(sample_data, function (d) {
        return d.y+5;
      })
    ]),

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xRange)
      .tickSize(5)
      .tickSubdivide(true)
      .tickFormat(d3.format("d")),

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yRange)
      .tickSize(5)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSubdivide(true);

//Drawing of the svg path

  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);

  var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return xRange(d.x);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return yRange(d.y);
  })
  .interpolate('monotone'); 

  vis.append("svg:path") //Dodavanje grafika na plot
    .attr("d", lineFunc(sample_podaci))
    .attr("id", "serija")
    .attr("stroke", "#00aedb")
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("fill", "none")

//Drawing of the keypoints (data points)

  vis.selectAll("line.circle")
    .data(sample_podaci)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr(
    {
      "class": "circle",
      "cx" : function(d) { return xRange(d.x); },
      "cy" : function(d) { return yRange(d.y); },
      "r" : 5,
      "ta_id" : function(d) { return d.id; },
      "fill" : "#e3a21a"
    })
    .call(drag_function);
```

Now in function *dragmove* I manage to translate the coordinates of points so they move along the y axis but it is only visually so since their cx and cy are not in the scale of the y axis at all. Also the coordinates of the path are suffering from this unusual values along the y axis.

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dicojopama/2/edit?html,js,output) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knqs74d0/) demo of the entire process.

**UPDATE:**

I see now that a problem is with the way axis values are represented. Whenever I try to print out the y axis value it gives me the mouse relative mouse coordinates instead. So the confounding problem is:

How to extract actual values (by x and y) of points along the path so they can be, for example, printed out?

**Another UPDATE and a possible solution:**

In the meantime I have managed to solve the entire problem. The thing was that *d3.event.y* values are in mouse coordinates and my data is, well in data coordinate system, so there had to be a one-to-one copy function. Surprisingly d3 has *.ivert* method which allows for switching between coordinate systems. So I had only to change my *dragmove* method like this:

```
function dragmove(d) {
    var dragPoint = d3.select(this);
    dragPoint
     .attr("cy", d3.event.dy + parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cy")));
    var data_y = yRange(parseInt(dragPoint.attr("cy")));
    var no_tac = d3.select(this).attr("ta_id");
    sample_data[no_tac].y = yRange.invert(yRange.invert(data_y));
    var kriva_path = d3.select('path#serija');
    kriva_path.attr("d", lineFunc(sample_podaci) + 'P');
   }
```